# Parse email from LinkedIn v2 api

Tags: json, swift, linkedin-api

LinkedIn’s v2 API has a separate url to get email address. The JSON response is a single object array. Can someone help me parse that object to get email address? 
LinkedIn URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~)) returns this JSON

```
["elements": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600000e8e760>(
{
    handle = "urn:li:emailAddress:123456789";
    "handle~" =     {
        emailAddress = "john123@gmail.com";
    };
}
)
]
```

JSON response is put into String:Any object.

```
if let emailOnly = response.jsonObject as? [String: Any] {
let emailAddress = (emailOnly["elements"]
                    as? [String:Any])?["handle~"] as? String ?? ""
print("emailaddress is ->", emailAddress)
```

emailAddress is blank after the last statement.

Here is the complete code:

```
linkedinHelper.requestURL("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))", requestType: LinkedinSwiftRequestGet, success: {(response) -> Void in
        if let emailOnly = response.jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject {
            let emailAddress = (emailOnly["elements"]
                as? [String: Any])?["handle~"] as? String ?? ""
            print("emailaddress is ->", emailAddress)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow, could you please provide some sample code and a sample response object?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code snippet that worked.

```
linkedinHelper.requestURL("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))", requestType: LinkedinSwiftRequestGet, success: {(response) -> Void in
        if let dictEmailOnly = response.jsonObject as? [String: Any] {
            if let x = dictEmailOnly["elements"] as? [[String:Any]],
               let y = x.first {
                let linkedInEmail = (y["handle~"] as? [String: Any])?["emailAddress"] as? String ?? ""
                print(linkedInEmail)
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

with response you can do-> response.elements[0]["handle~"].emailAddress

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
->elements[0]->{"handle~"}->emailAddress
```

Comment: Yes this is absolutely perfect. I am using PHP Curl for getting the email of Authenticated user  by calling "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))&oauth2_access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN.